# Buesqueda en array por index JQuey

Tags: jquery, array

mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo un array posiciones = `['0','1'];`

y otro mas con datos como por ejemplo:

```
nombres = array(['nombre'=>'marcelo], ['nombre'=>'juan] ['nombre'=>'carlos])
```

el primer array me marca las posiciones o indices del segundo, es decir que debo bucar la posicion 0 y 1 en nombres

como podria realizar esto en Jquey?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías convertir primero el array asociativo en un array de objetos, y entonces aplicar:

```
var nombres = [{'nombre': 'marcelo'}, {'nombre': 'juan'} ,{'nombre': 'carlos'}];
```

`var names = nombres.filter((ele, i) => i <= Math.max(...[0, 1]));`